# Can a well posed initial value problem fail the criteria for the Fundamental Theorem of Existence and Uniqueness?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is the theorem bidirectional or not? i.e. we know if the conditions of the theorem apply, the IVP is well posed, but if the function is well posed, is it or is it not guaranteed to meet the criteria of the theorem? This is just a yes or no question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere online.

Answer (score 0):

I talked to my professor and he came up with a counterexample that shows the theorem is one directional.

Take the IVP x' = |x| and x(0)=0.

This equation fails the criteria for the FEUT, because the partial of the function w.r.t. x is discontinuous at x=0.

However, one solution is the equation x(t)=0. This equation has the property that x'=0=x=|x|, and x(0)=0.

It is also a unique solution as follows:

Take another solution such that y'=|y| and y(0)=0, and let z(t)=y(t)e^(-t).

Then z'(t)=-y(t)e^(-t)+y'(t)e^(-t). Since y'=|y| but y(0)=0, y'=y.

Thus, z'(t)=(-y(t)+y(t))e^(-t)=0

This means z(t) is a constant and z(t)=z(0) for all t.

Hence, y(t)e^(-t)=0

Which means y(t)=0 for all t, and the solution is unique.